# Specific integral approximates $f(0)$ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

While self-studying, I came across the following problem. In this problem, $f$ is a continuous, real-valued function on $[0,1]$ and $\alpha$ is a positive, real number.

Show that $\alpha \int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} f(x)dx \rightarrow f(0) \ as\ \alpha\rightarrow 0$.

Although this makes sense to me for a variety of reasons, I don't know where to start a rigorous proof.

Why it makes sense to me: $\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ meaning that viewing the $x^{\alpha-1}$ term as a weighting factor, we have a total weight of 1. Furthermore, the plot $x^{0-1}\rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ meaning that this weighting factor is concentrated around $x=0$ yielding the required limit approaching $f(0)$.

Any hints on how to start this would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Hint: Set $\alpha = 1/n$ and then break up the integral into $\int_0^{1/n}$ and $\int_{1/n}^1$. Try to show the latter integral goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and then figure out what happens to the first integral, given that you know what the eventual limit is supposed to be.

Comment: If we first assume $f$ is continuously differentiable on an interval containing $[0, 1]$, integration by parts gives
$$
\int_{0}^{1} (x^{\alpha})' f(x) dx = x^{\alpha} f(x)|_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha} f'(x) dx.
$$
In the last integral, as $\alpha \rightarrow 0+$, the graph of $x^{\alpha}$ tends (pointwise, but not uniformly on $[0, 1]$) to the constant $1$.  So, intuition suggests that the resulting value is close to
$$
f(1) - [ f(1) - f(0) ].
$$

If we now drop our simplifying assumption differentiability, then Stone-Weiestrass approximations of $f$ uniform on $[0,1]$ will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rigorous proof:

Substitute $t=x^{\alpha}$. Then, for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$,
$$\int_0^1 a x^{\alpha -1} f(x) dx = \int_0^1f(t^{1/ \alpha }) dt$$
In particular, as $\alpha \to 0$ the RHS converges to $\int_0^1 f(0) dt = f(0)$ by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I had never heard of the dominated convergence theorem before, but this solves the problem exactly. Cheers.